# Magento price rule on product base price without option?

Tags: product, custom-options, coupon, cart-rule

I saw a lot of questions about price rules, catalog price rules...etc but I can't find an answer to my question.

My product (imagine that it's a t-shirt) can have options (logo for example) so it looks like: t-shirt 10€, logo +5€ = 15€.

Now I want that my t-shirt becomes FREE (with a coupon code) but not the logo, so the total is 5€.

**I know that with catalog price rule it's possible but i can't create a coupon code if I do so**

How can I do this price rule? and have a coupon code to apply it?

Answer (score 1):

Catalog price rules apply on products.

Cart rules apply on orders.

So if you want to discount a product, you need a catalog price rule. And yes, these rules don't have a coupon code.

What you can do is have a coupon code which reduces the shirt by 15€ and I think you can even have a rule which discounts every qty by qty*15€ but building such a rule for products with different prices might be hard or even impossible.

Comment: I hoped that it was me who didn't understand how to do it but no... thank you for your answer :) However , i don't understand why it's impossible to do this because if you want to offer the t-shirt if the customer take an option, you can't... (it doesn't make sense like that but imagine it with glasses with differents lenses which can be expensive ...)